# JWT Authentication in JAVA .

Tags: java, jwt

I issue JWT token for each user login and verify it after each request but I can not store jwt to any where in memory. So How do I verify that the JWT I received is valid and not tempered in between.

Comment: You have to write a validation method for that.

Comment: Yeah. I know that I have to verify received header and payload with signature. But i am not able to achieve that right now. can you please share the code for that. I am using  SignatureAlgorithm.HS256; Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
final String secret = "{{secret used for signing}}";

try {

    final JWTVerifier verifier = new JWTVerifier(secret);
    final Map<String, Object> claims= verifier.verify(jwt);

} 
catch (JWTVerifyException e) 
{

    // Invalid Token
}
```

Or check out this repo for java library to sign and verify jwt token.

https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt

Comment: This doesn't help. I am using  "io.jsonwebtoken." to create my JWT.

Comment: ok, so I think you are looking for this https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt. He have sample code for verifying jwt token also.

Comment: This is what verifys JWT token otherwise thows exception.Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key).parseClaimsJws(compactJws);